# Dynamic SQL merge vertical and horisontal table

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic

How do I build a SELECT that merges a normal table with data from a column and value table?

EXAMPLE: 
I have a customer table like this.

```
╔════════════╦═══════╦═════════╗
║ Customerid ║ name  ║ ZipCode ║
╠════════════╬═══════╬═════════╣
║          1 ║ peter ║    3030 ║
║          2 ║ Hans  ║    4040 ║
╚════════════╩═══════╩═════════╝
```

What I want is this:

```
╔════════════╦═══════╦═════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╗
║ Customerid ║ name  ║ ZipCode ║ AccountNr ║ CarNumber ║
╠════════════╬═══════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║          1 ║ peter ║    3030 ║ jb-31234  ║ YSS-41    ║
║          2 ║ Hans  ║    4040 ║ jb-32234  ║ ABS-21    ║
╚════════════╩═══════╩═════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

The columns accountNr and car number are in a column and value table that corresponds.

```
    COLUMN TABLE
╔═════════════════════╦═════════════╗
║ customer_column_id  ║ column_name ║
╠═════════════════════╬═════════════╣
║                   1 ║ AccountNr   ║
║                   2 ║ CarNumber   ║
╚═════════════════════╩═════════════╝


    VALUE TABLE
╔════╦════════════╦══════════╦════════════════════╗
║ ID ║ customerid ║  value   ║ customer_column_id ║
╠════╬════════════╬══════════╬════════════════════╣
║  1 ║          1 ║ jb-31234 ║                  1 ║
║  2 ║          1 ║ YSS-41   ║                  2 ║
║  3 ║          2 ║ jb-32234 ║                  1 ║
║  4 ║          2 ║ ABS-21   ║                  2 ║
╚════╩════════════╩══════════╩════════════════════╝
```

EDIT:
The answer Dynamic column in SELECT statement postgres is not the same question. That question is  how to generate data from dynamic columns. It is simple enough and can be done by some of the answers, but also the crossstab funciton in prosgres which I have used before. The central issue in my question that I have a horisontal (normal) table AND 2 vertical tables and need to merge them to 1 so the first table have more columns in the view mode.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic column in SELECT statement postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374660/dynamic-column-in-select-statement-postgres)

Comment: @Troels Do you have only "AcountNr" and "CarNumber" that you wish to put in colummns or are they more ?

Comment: There are multiple columns. The system is created, so the user may add extra columns.

Comment: The answer Dynamic column in SELECT statement postgres is not the same question. That question is how to generate data from dynamic columns. It is simple enough and can be done by some of the answers, but also the crossstab funciton in prosgres which I have used before. The central issue in my question that I have a horisontal (normal) table AND 2 vertical tables and need to merge them to 1 so the first table have more columns in the view mode.

Comment: That's two Joins and a pivot. Per your comment, it's not clear what part you don't already know about the solution. Show what you tried?

Comment: Do you want to call it exactly from sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up with. It is super fast. It is one of my freinds code, which I give all the credit, where I did the changes.

What it does is this. It creates a view, where the first part is the customer table.

The LEFT OUTER JOINS is the dynamic part. So imagine, that I first grab the column names from the column table, iterate through them and create the dynamic SQL, adding the column name and their values.

The last part is the "show me" part. Since there may be 1.000.000.000 rows it would not go in a normal webserver. So the ROW_NUMBER gives the rows I need. It could be a part of the paging, example page 7-9 where there are 100 rows each.

```
 //EXAMPLE OF TOTAL PART
            string SQL = @"  WITH tmp__View AS(select * from customer as cust_tbl
              LEFT OUTER JOIN(SELECT Value AS accountNumber, customer_id
                FROM col_extra_val  WHERE customer_column_id = 20) AS KeyTable1 ON KeyTable1.customer_id = cust_tbl.customer_id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN(SELECT Value AS lala, customer_id
                  FROM col_extra_val  WHERE customer_column_id = 19) AS KeyTable2 ON KeyTable2.customer_id = cust_tbl.customer_id
             order by cust_tbl.customer_id
            )
            SELECT* from
            (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY accountNumber DESC) As tmp__RowNumber FROM tmp__View) As tmp__TestTable
            WHERE tmp__RowNumber BETWEEN  700 AND   900;"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Here table1 indicates your first table,VT indicate value table and CV indicate Column table

```
select  customerid,Name, value.vl as AccountNr, cvalue.cv as carnumber 
    from    table1
    /*Acount number*/
    left join
    (
    select  customerid,customer_column_id,value as vl
    from    table1
    left join VT as p 
        on  
    p.customerid=table1.customerid
    left join CT as f 
        on  
    f.Customer_column_id=p.Customer_column_id
        and where customer_column_id='1'
    ) as value 
        on  value.customerid=table1.customerid
    /*Car number*/
    left join
    (
    select  customerid,customer_column_id,value as cv
    from    table1
    left join VT as p 
        on  
    p.customerid=table1.customerid
    left join CT as f 
        on  
    f.Customer_column_id=p.Customer_column_id
        and where customer_column_id='2'
    ) as cvalue 
        on  value.customerid=table1.customerid
    group by    customerid,customer_column_id,accountno,carnumber
```

Execute this and tell me the output because i didn't run this. Depends on your output i can able to make some changes

Comment: Thanks. I will run it and return :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have option to build your query outside sql so i will recommend to do it following way

```
SELECT
  'SELECT c.Customerid, c.name, c.ZipCode, ' ||
  string_agg(
    'vt' || ct.customer_column_id || '.value AS ' || ct.column_name,
    ', ')
  || ' FROM customers c ' ||
  string_agg(
    ' LEFT JOIN value_table vt' || ct.customer_column_id || ' ON ' ||
    'vt' || ct.customer_column_id || '.customer_column_id = ' || ct.customer_column_id ||
    ' AND vt' || ct.customer_column_id || '.customerid = c.Customerid',
    ' ')
  || ' ORDER BY c.Customerid DESC '
  || ' OFFSET 0 LIMIT 100;'
FROM column_table ct;
```

The result will be a query with your "dynamic" columns like

```
SELECT
    c.Customerid,
    c.name,
    c.ZipCode,
    vt1.value AS AccountNr,
    vt2.value AS CarNumber
FROM customers c
    LEFT JOIN value_table vt1 ON vt1.customer_column_id = 1 AND vt1.customerid = c.Customerid
    LEFT JOIN value_table vt2 ON vt2.customer_column_id = 2 AND vt2.customerid = c.Customerid
ORDER BY c.Customerid DESC
OFFSET 0 LIMIT 100;
```