# Dyanmic Table name in Postgres query

Tags: postgresql

Is there any way to replace the table name in a query with value stored in another table ? This is in postgres sql

Eg

Meta_table

```
col1    | col 2
Table 1 | val1
Table 2 | val2
```

My requirement

```
select * 
from (select col1 from meta_table where col2 = val2)
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374660/dynamic-column-in-select-statement-postgres. In my eyes this is the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most flexible and efficient way is dynamically creating a `temporary view` using function:

```
create or replace function f_prepare(tname text, vname text) returns text language plpgsql as $$
begin
    execute format(
        'create or replace temporary view %I as select * from %I',
        vname, tname);
    return vname;
end $$;
```

Then you can use the created view in usual way, for example;

```
select f_prepare('pg_class', 'v_class');
select * from v_class where relname = 'pg_database'; -- Index on the source table will be used here
```

and using your code:

```
select f_prepare((select col1 from meta_table where col2 = 'val2'), 'v');
select * from v;
```

And as any other temporary objects, created views will not conflict with other sessions and will be dropped on disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the table name of a table, then you can just update the **relname** column in table **pg_class**.
But for this, you need admin access to the Postgresql.

The query goes like:-

```
update pg_class set relname='new_table_name' where relname='old_table_name';
```

So to do this in single line, You can do like this:

```
update pg_class set relname=(select col1 from meta_table where col2 = val2) where relname='old_table_name';
```

Comment: Messing with the system catalogs directly is a **really** bad advice. A table should be renamed using `ALTER TABLE ... RENAME``

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Do` statement with `cursor`:

Try This:

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  _query text;
  _cursor CONSTANT refcursor := '_cursor';
BEGIN
  _query := 'SELECT * FROM '|| (select col1 from meta_table where col2 = 'val1');
  OPEN _cursor FOR EXECUTE _query;
END
$$;

FETCH ALL FROM _cursor;
```